# sed multiple matches replacing first match value

Tags: bash, sed

I have file as

```
   File: `/etc/motd'
  Size: 17              Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 10125343    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  1340/    root)   Gid: (  1240/    root)
Access: 2019-04-10 09:34:35.000000000 +0500
Modify: 2019-03-30 19:22:13.000000000 +0500
Change: 2019-03-30 19:22:13.000000000 +0500
```

using `sed` I'm able to extract `root` as desired but second `root` is not displayed separately

`sed -n 's/.*\/\(.*\))/\1/p ;   s/.*Gid\:.*\/\(.*\))/\1/p'`

Comment: why not just `stat -c $'%U\n%G' /etc/motd`?

Comment: Smart choice, pls put in answer so i can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `-c` option of `stat` to print group and user name owning a file:

```
stat -c $'%U\n%G' /etc/motd
```